# Cube con validaciones en base de datos

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

Necesito ayuda con un procedimiento en BD. Este es un prodecimiento que recibe una serie de datos, pero pueden existir o no y a base de estos realiza un cube. No sé si es posible hacer el cube con validaciones para evitar los ifs seguidos y aprender cómo realizarlo si era posible.

```
CREATE TABLE Producto(
        id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
        nombre varchar(500) not null,
        idCategoria int foreign key references Categoria(id) not null,
        idSucursal int foreign key references Sucursal(id) not null
);
```

Lo que deseo hacer es un procedimiento:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Cube
@XCategoria int,
@XSucursal int
```

Donde puede recibir todos los parámetros o ninguno pero estos deciden por que se hace el cube. Si XCategoria = 1 y XSucursal = 0 solo XCategoria pero si XCategoria = 1 y XSucursal =  XCategoria y XSucursal.

De antemano agradecería un ejemplo.

Comment: ¿Qué es un _"cube"_?  Creo que entiendo el filtro que quieres aplicar y escribiría una respuesta si tuviera claro que es un _cube_.

Comment: El cube es una forma de ordenar y sumar datos en una BD. Lo puedes encontrar acá: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-cube/

Answer (score 2):

Siempre puedes montar un procedure que haga una query dinámica.

Pare el escenario que parece quieres plantear, asumo que tienes una tabla de categorias, sucursales, una tabla de ventas, y una tabla de productos.

```
Create table categoria (id int primary key, descripcion varchar(10));
Create table Sucursal (id int primary key, descripcion varchar(10));

CREATE TABLE Producto(
        id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
        nombre varchar(500) not null,
        idCategoria int foreign key references Categoria(id) not null,
        idSucursal int foreign key references Sucursal(id) not null
);
go
Insert into categoria (id, descripcion)
values (1,'cat a'),(2,'cat b');
Insert into Sucursal (id, descripcion)
values (1,'suc 1'),(2,'suc 2');
go
Insert into Producto ( nombre, idCategoria, idSucursal)
values
('a',1,1),
('b',2,1),
('c',1,1),
('d',1,2),
('e',2,2),
('f',1,2),
('g',2,2);
go
Create table ventas (id int identity(1,1), idProducto int, cantidad int)
go
insert into ventas (idProducto, cantidad)
values
(1,10),
(1,10),
(1,10),
(2,10),
(2,10),
(3,5),
(3,5),
(4,50),
(5,20),
(5,20),
(5,20),
(6,20),
(6,20),
(7,20);
go
```

Por tanto hay ventas para todos los productos. Es posible que sucursal, no encaje como producto, sino como parte de una operación, pero esa es otra pregunta.

Si montas un procedure que realiza una query dinámica, lo puedes trabajar tal que:

```
Create procedure miCube (
 @xcategoria int = 1, --default
 @xSucursal INT = 1 -- default
 )
 As
Begin
    Declare @query nvarchar(4000);
    Set @query = N'select p.nombre,';
    Set @query += (Select CASE WHEN @xcategoria = 1 THEN N'C.descripcion as categoria,' else '' end);
    Set @query += (Select CASE WHEN @xSucursal = 1 then N's.descripcion as sucursal,' else '' end);
    Set @query += N'sum (v.cantidad) as cantidad
                        from ventas v
                        inner join Producto p on v.idProducto = p.id
                        LEFT join categoria c on p.idCategoria = c.id
                        LEFT join Sucursal s on p.idSucursal =c.id
                        group by cube (p.nombre';

    Set @query += (Select CASE WHEN @xcategoria = 1 THEN N', C.descripcion' else N'' end);
    Set @query += (Select CASE WHEN @xSucursal = 1 then N', s.descripcion' else N'' end);
    Set @query += N');';

    EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @QUERY;
END
GO
```

Por tanto si ejecutas el procedure

```
exec miCube
```

[image: Resultado 1]

Pero si ejecutas

```
exec miCube 0, 1
```

[image: Resultado 2]

y si ejecutas

```
exec miCube 0, 0
```

[image: Resultado 3]